# Numpy failed to import and Cache entry deserialization failed

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi

I am using RaspberryPis for a project (I am a really really really beginner with them) and I am facing few issue while installing the cv2 module. I ran a script that didn't work, issue was `ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import`. I saw on a previous respond to the solution was `pip install -U numpy`. So I did `pip3 install -U numpy` as I am running my script on python3. This works for one of my Pi but the other one didn't work showing a message error `Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored`. I saw on some other forum that we have to remove the cache of it which I tried but did not work. Anyone has any advices on it ? Would be extremely helpful, thanks in advance